# React Native - How to open my application when click on file from local device

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am using React Native and Expo.
I have file with unique extension (For example: SomeFileName.xxx) and it contains some text.
I want when I try to open this file from the device, it will open the application (Android/IOS) and I need read the content of the file.

How can I do that?

Comment: You can use **DeepLinking**

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what is the extension of the file!,

And it also depends upon where the file is saved.

Everything is possible in react-native-cli but in Expo it comes with very limited possibilities,

Expo does have a file-system api that allows you to access local files on device!,You can read/write any file to local directories of device!.

Here's the doc for file system:- 
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/

Thanks!.